# Twisted rubiks cube

Tags: rubiks-cube, twisty-puzzles

I have a rubiks cube with two wrong corners. How should I twist it back to get the right orientation?[image]

Comment: These corners are not twisted - their orientation is correct since their white square lies in the white face. Instead they are permuted, i.e. they need to change location, in this case swapped. The duplicate question answers that.